# How can I list only hidden accounts with terminal command

Tags: accounts

I can list any local accounts on terminal with dscl commands and parameters. But I want to list only hidden account(s) with one single command. Can someone help me ?

```
#!/bin/bash

Username="testaccount"
Password="123456"

sudo sysadminctl -addUser $Username
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/$Username $Password
dscl . create /Users/$Username IsHidden 1

List1=$(dscl . -search /Users  Ishidden 1 )
List2=$(dscl . -list /Users  Ishidden 1 )

echo $List1
echo $List2
```

But results return as blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can :

```
dscl . -search /Users IsHidden 1
```

If you just want the account names, run

```
dscl . -list /Users IsHidden 1 | cut -f 1 -d' '
```

Comment: I already tried but result return as blank

Comment: @emre Details matter, in this case the difference between `Ishidden` and `IsHidden`.